pdftools – How to skip errors?
I have an R script that converts all pdf files to text, but the "pdftools" package runs into various errors and stops the process. I would like to include in the code that if it finds an error or unknown character, it will continue with the next word or page. If that is not possible, then continue with the next document. And at the end, summarize which document or which page the script missed. Any ideas?
#Packages
library(pdftools)
library(tesseract)

#OCR language
tesseract_download("eng")
tess_lang <- tesseract("eng")

#Path
pdf_folder <- "folder"

#Read all pdfs
pdf_files <- list.files(pdf_folder, pattern = "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE)

#Processing pdf files
for (pdf_file in pdf_files) {
  #Read pdf
  pdf_text_content <- pdf_text(pdf_file)
  
  #If the pdf file contains text
  if (any(nzchar(unlist(pdf_text_content)))) {
    #Save the contents of a text pdf file
    txt_filename <- sub("\\.pdf$", ".txt", pdf_file)
    writeLines(pdf_text_content, txt_filename)
  } else {
    #OCR processing of scanned pdf file
    ocr_text <- ocr(pdf_file, engine = tess_lang)
    txt_filename <- sub("\\.pdf$", ".txt", pdf_file)
    writeLines(ocr_text, txt_filename)
  }
}



tryCatch will be your friend. Help yourself by helping us to help you by providing a minimal reproducible example.

untested tryCatch(pdf_text(pdf_file), error = function(e) paste('error in ', pdf_file))
